# Compare a date in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, date

I am doing a script to evaluate the last connection of a user, for this, I get the last time it was connected, and I extract the user + the date of the last connection, what I need to do now is to see if that date is greater or less than "2022-05-20" for example, but my problem is, that I do not know how to compare two dates in bash.

This is my code;

```
while [ $i -le $size_students ]
    do
        # Get the user's login
        login=$(sed -n "${i}p" xxxx.txt)
        # Get the user's data
        user_data=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${bearer_token}" "https://xxxxxxxxx/${login}/locations_stats" --globoff)
        # Get the user's last location
        last_lotaction=$(echo $user_data | jq -r '.' | cut -d "\"" -f 2 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' | head -n 1)
        # if last_location is null or less than 2022-05-01, the user is not connected
        echo `$login: $last_location`
```

The output is:

```
EnzoZidane: 2022-03-17
```

Comment: _"I extract the user + the date of the last connection"_ OK, but what's the format of that date?

Comment: Please reduce the script and problem to the minimum required to show your problem. There is a lot of extra code that is not necessary for the problem.

Comment: If you can guarantee that all your months and days are formatted with a leading zero where applicable, *and* the order is year-month-day, then you can probably just do a string comparison: `"2022-05-31" < "2022-06-01"` evaluates to true, I think.

Comment: The script is updated, i reduce the code, thanks for the help

Comment: I just wanna know if $last_location is major or minus than X date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your date formats, a simple string comparison should yield the desired result:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
[[ 2022-05-20 > 2022-05-19 ]] && echo yes
[[ 2022-05-20 < 2022-05-19 ]] || echo no
```

Comment: Does not work, if [[$last_location < "2022-05-01"]]

Comment: never_connected_students.sh: line 55: 2022-05-01]]: No such file or directory

Comment: don't strip the spaces around `[[` and `]]`. `[[$last_location < "2022-05-01"]]` has not  the same meaning than `[[ $last_location < "2022-05-01" ]]`

Comment: if [ "$last_location" < "2022-05-01" ] and never_connected_students.sh: line 55: 2022-05-01: No such file or directory

Comment: @Bart Use double `[[` and `]]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that all your months and days are formatted with a leading zero where applicable, *and* the order is year-month-day, then you can probably just use a string comparison:

```
if [[ "2022-05-31" < "2022-06-01" ]] 
then 
    echo true
fi
```

Comment: Does not work :(

Comment: @Bart How "does not work"? The above yields "true" as output, and if I change `<` to `>`, it doesn't, so it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all you dates to `epoch` first, then you can compare two integers:

```
if [[ $(date --date="$last_location" +%s) < $(date --date="2022-05-20" +%s) ]]; then
    echo "before"
else
    echo "after"
fi
```

Epoch time is always an integer number.